# flutter Cannot load settings from .iml file Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

emphasized text
Cannot load settings from file 'C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\master.idea\master.iml': ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1] Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.Please correct the file content

[Event Log Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO1ru.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please show the content of your master.iml file, so other people have it easier to help you!

Answer (score 11):

this is actually an Android studio problem and not Flutter.

Close your IDE then open your project folder and look for `.idea` open it and look for `module.xml`. Delete that file and open Android studio again.

It will generate a new `*.iml` and `module.xml` files and that error won't be there

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by closing emulator and restart android studio then from terminal command run (flutter clean) and restart again, run your project and every thing will be ok.